# Firebase Database on Android - orderByChild not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase and that's my first App using Firebase. 
My App got 15 different Scores and I separate them with a Spinner. Each time a different score is selected, it shoult be re-sorted.
It works, it always shows the correct scores but not Ordered.

Database:

[image: database structure]

My Code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
Query myQuery;


database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = database.getReference().getRef().child("Users");

for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
    int x = i+1;
    if (i == spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
        prefsEdit.putInt("selectedScore", x).apply(); 
        myQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("score"+possibleScores.get(i)); 
        downloadScores();
        break;
    }
}


public void downloadScores() {
    myQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            users.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Users user = post.getValue(Users.class);
                users.add(user);
            }
            UsersList scoreAdapter = new UsersList(HighscoreActivity.this, users);
            scoreList.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And that's my result. For example Score 6

[image: screenshot]

I tried to use this too

```
myQuery = databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("highscores").orderByChild("score"+possibleScores.get(i));
```

and got this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.user.app.Users
```

So what I overlook?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to order the users by the highscore size?

Comment: Yes like a ranking. One user has 15 different scores and with the spinner the user can choose which from the scores is displayed.

Comment: your database structure please ?

Comment: Do you find solution ?

Comment: Nope, first of all the scores are sorted local